# Dynamic States with React Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to render an array using the `map()` function while giving each element its own unique className (based on the index value) using some established states. An element should change colour when clicked using hooks. I've run into a problem where `className = {"header" + {index}.index}` gives the correct state name (header0, header1, etc.) but corresponds to a string rather than the class names established with the same names.

```
const data = ["James", "John", "Jessica", "Jamie"];

export default function App() {
  const [header0, setHeader0] = useState("visable");
  const [header1, setHeader1] = useState("visable");
  const [header2, setHeader2] = useState("visable");
  const [header3, setHeader3] = useState("visable");

  const clicked = (index) => {
    if (index === 0) {
      setHeader0("invisible");
    } else if (index === 1) {
      setHeader1("invisible");
    }
    /*Is there an alternative like {setHeader + index} instead of this loop?*/
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Sample Project</h1>
      {data.map((value, index) => (
        <h1
          className={"header" + { index }.index}
          onClick={() => {
            clicked(index);
          }}
        >
          {/* classname should be the state "header0" but right now its just a string */}
          Hello {value}!
        </h1>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is a code sandbox of what I am trying, with a few comments where things are going wrong. Am I going about this problem the correct way?
https://codesandbox.io/s/wispy-star-38qvw?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

[image: Edit wispy-star-38qvw]

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a single state array for visibilities.

In addition, if you stash the index in the clicked element's HTML dataset (`data-index`), you don't need a separate closure/function for each index.

```js
const data = ["James", "John", "Jessica", "Jamie"];

function App() {
  const [visibilities, setVisibilities] = React.useState(() => data.map((x) => true));

  const handleClick = (event) => {
    const index = parseInt(event.currentTarget.dataset.index, 10);
    const newVisibilities = [...visibilities];
    newVisibilities[index] = !newVisibilities[index];
    setVisibilities(newVisibilities);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {data.map((value, index) => (
        <h1 data-index={index} onClick={handleClick} className={visibilities[index] ? "selected" : undefined}>
          Hello {value}, you are {visibilities[index] ? "visible" : "hidden"}!
        </h1>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("main"));
```

```css
.selected {
  background: lightgreen;
}

h1 {
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<main></main>
```

Comment: Wow, this looks really clean. Would this solution allow the updating of CSS as well? For instance, if James is clicked, can I set the colour to red?

Comment: Certainly, let me update the snippet to reflect that.

Comment: Done deal, @Jschriemer :)

Answer (score 2):

You are declaring 2 arguments in clicked function so `e` is the actual index.

Shoud be

```
const clicked = (index) => {
```

Comment: Ah I see thanks! Okay fixed that so I get the proper index onClick. However, the state still is not updating.. It must have something to do with the line ```className = {"header" + {index}.index}``` but I cant figure out what an alternative is

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid that is not a nice approach, but you can try this:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const data = ["James", "John", "Jessica", "Jamie"];

export default function App() {
  const headers = [];

  [headers[0], headers[1], headers[2], headers[3]] = [
    useState("visable"),
    useState("visable"),
    useState("visable"),
    useState("visable")
  ]; // each headers[index] is an array with [state, setState function]

  const clicked = (index) => {
    alert("clicked " + index);
    headers[index][1]("invisible");
    /*Is there an alternative like {setHeader + index} instead of this loop?*/
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Sample Project</h1>
      {data.map((value, index) => (
        <h1
          className={headers[index][0]}
          onClick={() => {
            clicked(index);
          }}
        >
          {/* classname should be the state "header0" but right now its just a string */}
          Hello {value}!
        </h1>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

the code pen: https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-rain-o31ms

Answer (score 0):

You can change the way you are structing the state to an array, then the click function will turn it invisible by index

```js
const data = ["James", "John", "Jessica", "Jamie"];

export default function App() {
    const [headersVisible, setHeaderVisible] = useState(
        data.map(() => "visible")
    );

    const clicked = (index) => {
        setHeaderVisible(
            headersVisible.map((val, ix) => (index === ix ? "invisible" : val))
        );
    };

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <h1>Sample Project</h1>
            {data.map((value, index) => (
                <h1
                    key={index}
                    className={headersVisible[index]}
                    onClick={()=>clicked(index)}
                >
                    {/* classname should be the state "header0" but right now its just a string */}
                    Hello {value}!
                </h1>
            ))}
        </div>
    );
}
```