# add dynamic useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

[I see this link but didn't get any answer for my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65172155/dynamic-states-with-react-hooks)

in my component , I have a two selectbox and one txtarea that owned Specified state(define by use state).

so on click add button this form create again and again,
my question is how to define new state dynamicly  to set it for new selectbox that dynamicly created.
my select box use react-select and code of them is here :

```
      <div className="mqContainer">
        {[...Array(mqCount)].map((x, i) => (
          <div key={i} className="newMqWrapper mt-4">
            <Row className="mt-4">
              <Col xs={3}>
                <span>milestone</span>
              </Col>
              <Col xs={6}>
                <Select
                  style={{ width: "100px !important" }}
                  defaultValue={mileStoneType}
                  onChange={setmileStoneType}
                  options={MileStoneTypeOption}
                  isMulti={true}
                />{" "}
              </Col>
            </Row>
            <Row className="mt-4">
              <Col xs={3}>
                <span>question text</span>
              </Col>
              <Col xs={8}>
                <Form.Group>
                  <Form.Control
                    placeholder="why so serious?"
                    className=" dirrtl"
                    as="textarea"
                    rows={3}
                  />
                </Form.Group>{" "}
              </Col>
            </Row>
            <Row className="mt-4">
              <Col xs={3}>
                <span>answer type</span>
              </Col>
              <Col xs={6} className="mb-4">
                <Select
                  defaultValue={mileStoneAnswerType}
                  onChange={setmileStoneAnswerType}
                  options={MqAnswerTypeOption}
                />{" "}
              </Col>
            </Row>
          </div>
        ))}
        <Row>
          <Col xs={12} className=" mb-4 mt-4">
            <Button
              onClick={() => setMqCount(mqCount + 1)}
              style={{ width: "100%" }}
              variant="outline-secondary"
            >
              +
            </Button>{" "}
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </div>
```

[image]

Comment: This is just a part of your whole code snippet. Mind if you could add [minimal reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @decpk thanks. i added all of component code.just state defenition not added

Comment: You can't. A component must *always* run the same hooks in the same order. That's why the answers to the question you reference use a single state and put an array in it.

Answer (score 1):

I hope that I understand your problem correctly.

Regularly, you would create a Component in which you can call useState() separately. After that, you can render it inside your map().

I tried to reproduce your structure:

```js
import { useState } from 'react'

const Form = () => {
  const [ mqCount, setMqCount ] = useState(0)

  return (
    <div className='mqContainer'>
      {[ ...Array(mqCount) ].map((x, i) => {
        // TODO: pass your required props here
        return <Item key={i} />
      })}
      <Row>
        <Col className='mb-4 mt-4' xs={12}>
          <Button
            style={{ width: '100%' }}
            variant='outline-secondary'
            onClick={() => setMqCount(mqCount + 1)}
          >
            +
          </Button>{' '}
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </div>
  )
}

const Item = ({ mileStoneType, MileStoneTypeOption, setmileStoneType }) => {
  const [ yourState, setYourState ] = useState('Whatever you want')
  // TODO: replace it with your own state

  return (
    <div key={i} className='newMqWrapper mt-4'>
      <Row className='mt-4'>
        <Col xs={3}>
          <span>milestone</span>
        </Col>
        <Col xs={6}>
          <Select
            isMulti
            defaultValue={mileStoneType}
            options={MileStoneTypeOption}
            style={{ width: '100px !important' }}
            onChange={setmileStoneType}
          />{' '}
        </Col>
      </Row>
      <Row className='mt-4'>
        <Col xs={3}>
          <span>question text</span>
        </Col>
        <Col xs={8}>
          <Form.Group>
            <Form.Control
              as='textarea'
              className=' dirrtl'
              placeholder='why so serious?'
              rows={3}
            />
          </Form.Group>{' '}
        </Col>
      </Row>
      <Row className='mt-4'>
        <Col xs={3}>
          <span>answer type</span>
        </Col>
        <Col className='mb-4' xs={6}>
          <Select
            defaultValue={mileStoneAnswerType}
            options={MqAnswerTypeOption}
            onChange={setmileStoneAnswerType}
          />{' '}
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </div>
  )
}
```